# Find range of values for function to be onto

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ where $f(x)=\dfrac{ax^2+6x-8}{a+6x-8x^2}$

Find the range of values of $a$ for which $f$ is onto.

I tried many thing like assuming it to be $y$ then the $D\geq 0$, what values of $a$ makes $x$ value real, taking slope and finding if function goes till infinity.
But was not able to find.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to have "$8x^2$" instead of "$8x$" in the denominator?

Comment: Yes, I m sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$k=\dfrac{ax^2+6x-8}{a+6x-8x^2}\\k(-8x^2+6x+a)=ax^2+6x-8\\(-8k-a)x^2+(6k-6)x+(ak+8)$$
Now find a such that for every $k\in\mathbb{R}$ you have that $D\geq 0$